# OpenSea API V2 - Invalid order signature while creating listing

Tags: python, signature, opensea

I want to create listing via OpenSea API with Python. I have response: `{"errors":["['Invalid order signature']"]}`. I couldn't find and information in docs what to sign. Currently I am signing Order Parameters. Here is my code:

```py
import requests
from web3.auto import w3
from eth_account.messages import encode_defunct
import time


def create_order_model():
    current_time = int(time.time())
    order = {
        "offerer": "0xd107AC5e5830BB95f880cA3b1270ccCdAA0A3c5e",
        "zone": "0x00000000e88fe2628ebc5da81d2b3cead633e89e",
        "zoneHash": "0x3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "startTime": current_time,
        "endTime": current_time + 2629743, # current_time + 1 month in seconds
        "orderType": 2,
        "offer": [
            {
                "itemType": 2,
                "token": "0x45aeb17Db4dd06FF9Ca6cB1E37455AAF761Bdc14",
                "identifierOrCriteria": "1",
                "startAmount": "1",
                "endAmount": "1",
            },
        ],
        "consideration": [
            {
                "itemType": 0,
                "token": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "identifierOrCriteria": "0",
                "startAmount": "9750000000000000000",
                "endAmount": "9750000000000000000",
                "recipient": "0xd107AC5e5830BB95f880cA3b1270ccCdAA0A3c5e",
            },
            {
                "itemType": 0,
                "token": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "identifierOrCriteria": "0",
                "startAmount": "250000000000000000",
                "endAmount": "250000000000000000",
                "recipient": "0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8",
            },
        ],
        "totalOriginalConsiderationItems": 2,
        "salt": 12686911856931635052326433555881236148,
        "conduitKey": "0x0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000",
        "nonce": 0,
        "counter": 0
    }
    return order

def sing_order(msg):
    private_key = "PRIVATE_KEY"
    message = encode_defunct(text=str(msg))
    signed_message = w3.eth.account.sign_message(message, private_key=private_key)
    return signed_message.signature.hex()



def main():
    url = "https://testnets-api.opensea.io/v2/orders/goerli/seaport/listings"
    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json"
    }

    order_parameters = create_order_model()
    print(order_parameters)

    signature = sing_order(order_parameters)
    print(signature)

    params = {"parameters": order_parameters, "signature": str(signature)}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=params)
    print(response.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Inside `seaport-js`(SDK for javascript: https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/seaport-js/blob/fb1c40d776070a8ee57735ad17f2bdb4a91ac7c6/src/seaport.ts#L386) I found that there is function to sign data `singOrder()` and tried to convert this idea to Python. This is how converted by me sign_order look:

```py
def sing_order(msg):
    private_key = "PRIVATE_KEY"
    domain_data = {
        "name": "Seaport",
        "version": "1.1",
        "chainId": 5,
        "verifyingContract": "0x00000000e88fe2628ebc5da81d2b3cead633e89e",
    }
    eip_721_order_type = {
        "OrderComponents": [
            {"name": "offerer", "type": "address"},
            {"name": "zone", "type": "address"},
            {"name": "offer", "type": "OfferItem[]"},
            {"name": "consideration", "type": "ConsiderationItem[]"},
            {"name": "orderType", "type": "uint8"},
            {"name": "startTime", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "endTime", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "zoneHash", "type": "bytes32"},
            {"name": "salt", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "conduitKey", "type": "bytes32"},
            {"name": "counter", "type": "uint256"},
        ],
        "OfferItem": [
            {"name": "itemType", "type": "uint8"},
            {"name": "token", "type": "address"},
            {"name": "identifierOrCriteria", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "startAmount", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "endAmount", "type": "uint256"},
        ],
        "ConsiderationItem": [
            {"name": "itemType", "type": "uint8"},
            {"name": "token", "type": "address"},
            {"name": "identifierOrCriteria", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "startAmount", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "endAmount", "type": "uint256"},
            {"name": "recipient", "type": "address"},
        ],
    }
    order_components = str(msg)
    message = encode_defunct(text=(str(domain_data) + str(eip_721_order_type) + str(order_components)))
    signed_message = w3.eth.account.sign_message(message, private_key=private_key)
    return signed_message.signature.hex()
```

**Do you know how to properly sign an order that will be acceptable by OpenSea API?**